# Filtrar a fila de análises por tag?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Eu sei que posso estar sendo específico demais na minha questão. Adquiri recentemente o privilégio de aprovar edições e mais algumas coisas. Enfim, agora consigo monitorar a fila de análises com mais frequência e quase sempre tenho algo pra analisar.

Em alguns casos devo admitir que fico um pouco perdido. Por não conhecer algumas linguagens eu não sei se aprovo ou desaprovo algumas edições em que são removidos métodos, nomes de frameworks e o que há de mais em linguagens de programação na postagem, então, por vezes, eu clico em **Pular**.

Há uma maneira de "filtrar" a fila de análise apenas em perguntas que possuem a tag que eu tenho conhecimento para analisar? Isso seria uma má ideia?

<sup>Obs.: Sei que esse não é o propósito da fila de análise, apenas achei interessante ter essa ferramenta.</sup>

Comment: Não há de forma oficial, deve dar pra fazer alguma gambi, mas não deve valer o esforço. É um bom pedido.

Comment: Acho que já tem um recurso parecido => https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx08g.jpg não sei se chegou a ver.

Comment: @rray, nossa! Sim! Era isso mesmo. O botão está um pouco escondido, realmente não o vi. Embora limitado acho que consigo filtrar pelos meus interesses. Admito que estava procurando por algo parecido com as tags favoritas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No cabeçalho da da fila de análise tem link (discerto) filtro, ele permite marcar qual contéudo você deseja ver, cada fila têm opção diferentes além da seleção de tags que no mamixo são três.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]